# If the series $a_n$ converges to $L \in (-1,1)$ then the series $a_n^n$ converges to 0

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Title.

The statement is True. I explained it using limit arithmetic:

Saying that if a series converges to a number between 1 and -1 if you power it by n the series will converge to 0 ($\frac{1}{"infinity"}$) but got zero because my explantion isn't true.

Can someone tell me where did I go wrong and what is the real explantion for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is a standard proof of real analysis. If $|x|<1$ then $x^n \to 0$ an $n \to \infty$. see any basic Analysis book.

Comment: Why can't I use arithmetics for that?

Comment: Please add your answer to the question to help in

Comment: I told what I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially what you did was take two limits separately; that is, implicitly you used: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n^n = \lim_{n\to \infty} \big(\lim_{m\to\infty}a_m\big)^n$$ which does not always hold (the classic examples where this doesn't hold would be $a_n = 1+ \frac{1}{n}$ or $b_n = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$). Instead, since you know your sequence goes to a number in $(-1,1)$ you can start by bounding your sequence away from $1$ and then use a comparison test. For example, say $a_n \to L \in (-1,1)$. Since $L \in (-1,1)$ which is an open set, we can find $\epsilon > 0$ such that $(L-\epsilon , L + \epsilon) \subset (-1,1)$. For such $\epsilon$, there is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $n \ge N$ gives $$\lvert a_n - L\rvert < \epsilon/2.$$ Then for sufficiently large $n$ we have $\lvert a_n \rvert < 1- \epsilon/2$ [Do you see why?]. Then for such $n$, we have $$\lvert a_n^n \rvert = \lvert a_n \rvert ^n  < (1-\epsilon/2)^n$$ whereupon sending $n \to \infty$ gives $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n^n = 0$ by the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier,
I'll assume the limit $L > 0$.
If $L < 0$,
this will show that
$|a_n^n| \to 0$
so that
$a_n^n \to 0$.

Since $L > 0$,
let $d = \min(L, 1-L)/2$.
For large enough $n$,
$L-d < a_n < L+d$.

Therefore
$0 < a_n^n
< (L+d)^n
$.

(This next part is not original.)

Since
$0 < L+d < 1$,
let
$a =\frac1{L+d}-1$,
so that
$a > 0$.

By Bernoulli's inequality,
$(1+a)^n
\ge 1+na
\gt na
$
so that
$\frac1{(1+a)^n}
\lt \frac1{na}
$.

Therefore
$\frac1{na}
\gt \frac1{(1+a)^n}
= \frac1{(1+(\frac1{L+d}-1))^n}
= \frac1{(\frac1{L+d})^n}
= (L+d)^n
\gt (a_n)^n
$
so that
$a_n^n < \frac1{an}
\to 0$.